# Writing a piece of C code such that compiler uses SSE4.1 instruction for generating assembly Code

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, sse, simd

I want to write some C code such that gcc using the `-msse4.1` flag can optimize it. Basically I want to check whether or not the compiler is taking advantage of SSE4.1 instructions. 
There are many SSE4.1 instructions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#New_instructions) but I am not able to write a fragment of C Code which is using any of those instructions in the generated assembly code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt GCC would emit SSE4.1 instructions that easily. But you could have a look at [Intel SPMD Program Compiler](http://ispc.github.com/):

> Under the SPMD model, the programmer writes a program that mostly
>   appears to be a regular serial program, though the execution model is
>   actually that a number of program instances execute in parallel on the
>   hardware. (See a more detailed example that illustrates this concept.)
>   ispc compiles a C-based SPMD programming language to run on the SIMD
>   units of CPUs; it frequently provides a 3x or more speedup on CPUs
>   with 4-wide SSE units, without any of the difficulty of writing
>   intrinsics code.

Answer (score 5):

From what I've seen, compilers rarely ever generate SSE4.1 instructions. I've seen a few cases where it will use the insert/extract instructions to pack data.

But for the most part, if you want to use the SSE4.1 instructions, you need to do them explicitly using intrinsics:

http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_bk_sse41.htm